# Streamreader freezing on close

Tags: c#

I have an app that reads tweets from Twitter based on keywords.  Those keywords can change periodically, and when they do, I need to close and re-open the stream.  I am able to open the stream no problem, but I am having an issue when I tried to close that stream.  Here is some example code:

```
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    WriteLogMessage("Stream open - entering loop");
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (count == 10) break;
                        count++;

                        string tweet = reader.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write(tweet);
                    }

                    WriteLogMessage("Exited loop");
                }
                /**** Program seems to freeze and never gets past this point ****/
                WriteLogMessage("Reader disposed");
            }
            WriteLogMessage("Stream disposed");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLogMessage(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
                response.Dispose();
            WriteLogMessage("Response closed");
        }
```

This code runs fine on my win7 (x64) machine.  However, when I deploy it to either server 2008 or server 2012 (both x64), I see this freezing behavior.  I am setting no parameters on the HttpWebRequest other than a header that twitter requires.  Anyone have any thoughts about whats going on?

Comment: Try with just one `using` statement: `using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))`. I guess the problem comes from closing twice the same stream.

Comment: what is count and where is it defined ? also why don't you change the line in `reader.ReadLine` to `reader.ReadToEnd();`

Comment: @DJKRAZE OP seems to use [Twitter's streaming API](https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json) which never ends....

Comment: Oh that would make sense then..lol I've noticed that he's calling `response.Dispose()` I in my opinion I think it's better to just call `response.Close()` or if he really wants to eliminate the `Finally{}` he should wrap the `response object` around a `using()`

Comment: @caerolus I've tried just using 1 using statement, same result.  Yes, I'm using the twitter streaming API.. which sends data continuously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this from time to time. For reasons I don't fully understand, the stream wants to stay open until it's received everything. This became such a problem for me that I'd call `request.Abort` before closing the stream. In your code, for example, I would write:

```
    WriteLogMessage("Exited loop");
    request.Abort();
}
```

I blogged about it some time back: http://www.informit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=The-hanging-web-request